# How do I get information about why SourceTree failed to commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I've just started using SourceTree, and really version control in general, though I've used GitHub while working on a project a year or two back, so I have an idea of how it should work. I'm using SourceTree on Windows 10, and hosting a repo on BitBucket. So far, so good - the empty repo shows up on BitBucket, and I can see it in SourceTree. Here's where the problem starts. I added files to the repository folder on my computer manually, and attempted to commit them to the master branch. Upon doing so, I get a progress bar which fills, then turns red. Clicking the "Show Full Output" button gives me a massive wall of text containing the file names of all the files I committed (of which there are many). At the very end of this wall of text, a single line says "Completed With Errors, See Above." How do I find what the problem is based on this? Maybe as a beginner I'm missing something very obvious. Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

So I emptied the folder, committed that without error, added the files again, committed and pushed without any problems. My problem is resolved, but I'd still like to know the answer to the question! Thanks.